# Filling HTML Table with Javascript - SLOW

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I'm having trouble filling a HTML table with javascript efficiently.

For some background; I have a database with around 270k~ entries. I'm using the Javascript Fetch API to retrieve the rows of the SQL database from flask (i.e. my backend). The data transfer is fast - for example I can get the size of the database in less than a second, so that's not the bottleneck.

However, when I loop over the fetch results and try to fill a HTML table with even 50,000 entries, it takes over 15 seconds and the app locks up.

I have read this could be because I'm reading from the DOM, and that reading from native JS storage would be faster.

Would anyone have suggestions on how to solve this bottleneck?

My functions are below - I'm simply looping over the fetch promise and filling with the info.

```
async function getDB(){
  let x;

  console.log('Trying to get the entire database')
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/getDB')
      .then(function (response){
          return response.json();

      }).then(function (data) {
          x = data
      })
  
  return x

};

function fillData(results){
  // Dynamically filling the data...

  results.then(
      function(value) {

          var table = document.getElementById("transactions-table");

          let sortable = [];
          for(var key in value){
              // console.log(key + ": " +  value[key]);
              sortable.push([key, value[key]])
              // console.log(key + )
          }

          sortable.sort(function(a, b){
              return a[1] - b[1];
          })

          for(var key in value){

              var row = table.insertRow(key);
              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);    // <th>Id</th>
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);    // <th>Forename</th>
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);    // <th>Surname</th>
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);    // <th>Location</th>  
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);    // <th>Amount</th>     

              cell1.innerHTML = value[key][0]
              cell2.innerHTML = value[key][1]  // Needs to be an index of the row tuple
              cell3.innerHTML = value[key][2]  // Needs to be an index of the row tuple
              cell4.innerHTML = value[key][3]  // Needs to be an index of the row tuple
              cell5.innerHTML = value[key][4]  // Needs to be an index of the row tuple

              // row.style.backgroundColor = "red"
          }
          
          var row = table.insertRow(0);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3)
          var cell5 = row.insertCell(4)

          cell1.innerHTML = "<b>ID</b>"
          cell2.innerHTML = "<b>Forename</b>"
          cell3.innerHTML = "<b>Surname</b>"
          cell4.innerHTML = "<b>Location</b>"
          cell5.innerHTML = "<b>Amount</b>"
      },

      function(error) {
          console.log('Oh damn')
          console.log(error)
      }
  )
}
```

No method I can think of so far.

Comment: You shouldn't be loading 50k results at once. Implement backend pagination and only fetch around 50-200 results at once. You could have a button under your table called "load more" then you fetch the next batch of results and update your table. Or you could just have two buttons "previous" and "next" to regenerate your table with the results of a specific page.

Comment: If you really don't want to use pagination, then consider using document.createElement instead of innerHTML. innerHTML is known to be much slower.

Comment: Also, tables can be slow. Changing table data may cause the entire table to recompute its layout, which eats up page rendering time. It would be better to assemble all additions and THEN add them to the table all at once.